# Can I use the same "role" attribute in different elements that have the same purpose?

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

Can I use the same `role` attribute in different elements that share the same functionality?

For example, the same logo in different parts of a website, or multiple svg icons which are all `role: button`.

I read somewhere this is malpractise but I don't really know how to get around this without losing the accessibility of my website. Should I just change the roles to non-WAI ones like "button1", "button2"...?

Answer (score 3):

There may be some confusion here between the `id` attribute, which is expected to have a value that is unique inside the HTML page, and the `role` attribute, which identifies the type of UI components.

If you have SVG icons that *function as buttons*, then `role="button"` is correct, regardless how many such buttons you have in a page. There is no rule that says you can only have one button in a web page. On the contrary; if you want to make accessible each SVG icon that functions as a button, then you *should* assign them `role="button"` and make them keyboard accessible.

While the list of ARIA role values is [strictly speaking non-normative](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#allowed-aria-role-attribute-values) from the point of view of the HTML5 specification, making up your own role values does not make much sense. WAI-ARIA developed the "role taxonomy" based on what types of UI components are/were supported in existing accessibility APIs. This is the background behind the [mapping between WAI-ARIA and accessibility APIs](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-implementation/#mapping) in the *WAI-ARIA 1.0 User Agent Implementation Guide*. "button" is a type of UI component that accessibility APIs commonly support. "button1", "button2" are not UI components that accessibility APIs support.

In short, giving your SVG icons attributes such as `role="button1"`, `role="button2"` is a bad idea; use `role="button"` for each such icon that functions as a button.